# How to get whatsapp api link from from notification extras

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app that filters WhatsApp notification by keyword
My qs is if a notification comes from a group
can I extract the group API link from the `sbn.getNotification().extras`
extract the text and the title seems to be easy with

```
extras.getString("android.title");
extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
```

Is there a way to check if a notification comes from a group and if so
then extract the WhatsApp API group link

I tried using this `sbn.getNotification().extras`
and look for a way to extract group API link